# DISTINCT COUNT with GROUP BY query is too slow despite indexes

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have the following query that counts the number of vessels in each zone for each week:

```
SELECT zone, 
    DATE_FORMAT(creation_date, '%Y%u') AS date, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT vessel_imo) AS vessel_count 
  FROM vessel_position
  WHERE zone IS NOT NULL
   AND creation_date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH)
  GROUP BY zone, date;
```

The table has about 40 million rows. The execution plan for this is:

```
+----+-------------+-----------------+------------+-------+--------------------+------+---------+------+----------+----------+------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table           | partitions | type  | possible_keys      | key  | key_len | ref  | rows     | filtered | Extra                                    |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------------+-------+--------------------+------+---------+------+----------+----------+------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | vessel_position | NULL       | range | creation_date,zone | zone | 5       | NULL | 21190904 |    50.00 | Using where; Using index; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------------+-------+--------------------+------+---------+------+----------+----------+------------------------------------------+
```

Columns `vessel_imo`, `zone` and `creation_date` each indexed. Primary key is the composite key (`vessel_imo`, `creation_date`).

When I look at the query profile, I can see that a large amount of time i spent doing `Creating sort index`.

Is there anything I can do to improve this query further?

Comment: Are most of the 21 million rows older than 1 year?

Comment: @RolandStarke No, there's a lot of data each month. About a million.

Comment: Mh, no clue, maybe you could try changing the group by to `date, zone` (as the rows are probably ordered by date and not zone) but i don't think it will do much.

Comment: Please post text results of A) SHOW CREATE TABLE vessel_position  and  B) SHOW INDEX FROM vessel_position  for analysis.  How long is this query running?

Comment: Do you understand that the first row will be a partial week, hence the `COUNT-DISTINCT` will probably be a bit low?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; there may be some tricks to do there.  How much RAM do you have?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  How often is this query run?  (That is, can we do some kind of caching to improve the operation?)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the data, once inserted, does not change, then build and maintain a Summary Table.

The table would have three columns: the zone, the week, and the count-distinct for that week.  At the start of each week, build *only* the rows for the previous week (one per zone; skip `NULL`).  Then build a query to work against that table -- it will be extremely fast since it will be fetching far fewer rows.

Meanwhile, the `INDEX(creation_date, zone, vessel_imo)` as a secondary index, will make the weekly task reasonably efficient (~52 times as fast as your current query).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how selective your filtering condition is, and your table structure. Does the filtering condition selects 20% of the rows, 5%, 1%, 0.1%?

If your answer is less than 5% then the following index could help:

```
create index ix1_date_zone on vessel_position (creation_date, zone);
```

If your table has many and/or heavy columns, then this option could still be slow, depending on how selective your filtering condition is.

Otherwise, you could try using a more **expensive** index, to avoid using the table and do:

```
create index ix2_date_zone_imo on vessel_position 
  (creation_date, zone, vessel_imo);
```

This index is more expensive to maintain -- read `insert`, `update`, `delete` rows -- but it would be faster for your `select`.

Try both options and pick the best for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

SET @mystartdate = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH);

SELECT zone, DATE_FORMAT(creation_date, '%Y%u') AS date, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT vessel_imo) AS vessel_count 
    FROM vessel_position
    WHERE creation_date >= @mystartdate
      AND zone > 0
    GROUP BY zone, date;

may provide results in less time, please post your comparative times of second run of each ( old and suggested )

Please post new EXPLAIN SELECT … to confirm index of creation date is now used.

Unless old data is allowed to change, why do you have to gather 12 months history, the numbers more than 1 month ago are NOT going to change.